# Shimano R7020 Shifter leak

Tags: shimano, shifter

I have new bike with Shimano 105 R7020 and my left shifter has some oil/ grease on the spindle (see picture).

[image]

If I wash and wipe it and will show up again. I checked the oil reservoir and there is no leak and the braking function is normal. I already claimed the warranty and replaced with a new shifter but has the same oil/grease spot in the new shifter (left side of the spindle only). Is it only grease from the spindle or there is a leak on the hydraulic system? I do not find this on my right shifter.

[image]

Comment: Did you check under the rubber hood? Shimano lever axes are not greased.

Comment: Yes, i already open the hood but no oil/fluid on the bladder, on the mineral oil cap, all dry, i try washing and wipe it and has this spot on the spindle again after a couple hours. it look like the grease/oil come out from the spindle even when i am not using the bike, i dont know is anyone has the same issue? since it already replace with the new shifter but has the same issue.

Comment: What is the ambient temperature like where you live. Is it hot at the moment?

Comment: Hi Joe, yes the temperature where i live is about 32 C/ 89 F (tropical), i ride my bike on weekend only.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are in a hot environment and the apparent leak is on the left hand side, I think the grease spot is the oils moving out from the gear shifting mechanism and displaying themselves this way. It is less likely to be the resins of the shifter body and even less likely to be mineral oil escaping from the braking system as this oil is very stable for high temperatures found in braking.

My hypothesis why this is visible only on the left is that the majority of people lean their bike against the left hand side when not in use (with the drivetrain visible away from the wall) so the path out to the end of the lever pivot is downwards on the left, and upwards on the right.

I would only worry about braking if you find the brake action starts to change noticeably. Generally a leak that is likely to affect your safety is also a leak that is quite obvious. Everyone should have a feel for if the brakes are right or wrong when they set out on a ride.

Comment: Thank you @JoeK, the braking work normal.